# Field validation bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this code for validating form field:

```
        $("#prospectForm").validate({
        rules: {
            Orgnr: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 9,
                maxlength: 9
            },
            Firmanavn: {
                required: true
            },
            Postnr: {
                number: true
            },
            Antall_ansatte: {
                number: true
            },
            Etableringsar: {
                number: true
            },
            Ekstra_Tall: {
                number: true
            }
        }
    });
```

But I got the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element Orgnr, check the '__dummy__' method.`

I looked at `jquery.validate.js` and found in which line the problem is:

```
result = $.validator.methods[ method ].call( this, val, element, rule.parameters );
```

Here the method has `__dummy__` value and `methods["__dummy__"]` is `undefined`.

Anyone knows what can be the problem?

Comment: Can you post your html form aswell?

Comment: The burden is on you to post enough code that reproduces the issue.  So where is the HTML markup for the form?  Otherwise as you can see, the code you posted is working fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/hL6L0c5a/

Comment: I am facing same issue. Unobtrusive validation breaks on error: TypeError: $.validator.methods[method] is undefined & methos id __dummy__. I dont know what is this __dummy__ rule and why it is being applied by default. I am using ASP.NET MVC, which includes rules automatically

Answer (score 1):

Or, alternatively one could do:

```
$.validator.addMethod("__dummy__", function (value, element) {
    return true;
});
```

<strike>However - don't have any clue what's wrong.</strike>

**EDIT:**

Accidentally I included jquery.validate.js twice.

Answer (score 1):

I just leave a comment here for future reference, some ready to use UI libraries already has validation embedded to their main library so we just need to remove the reference to jquery.validate.min.js

Answer (score 0):

We solved it by removing `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` attributes which `Asp.Net MVC` framework automatically generate from Model annotations. If anyone is interested you remove this by putting `{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }` in razor view.

Comment: You didn't show any HTML markup or mention anything about ASP, MVC, Unobtrusive plugin, or Razor in your OP, so nobody else could have answered your question as it was presented.